# What's the easiest way to bluebird promisify a function with its callback as the second-to-last value?

Tags: bluebird

I'm trying to promisify this [geocoder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geocoder) library for connecting to an external api. The readme says that its `geocoder.geocode` method takes `location, callback` as arguments, but [on closer inspection](https://github.com/wyattdanger/geocoder/blob/master/index.js#L60-L68), it actually takes a third argument — an options object — so it can't be easily promisified with bluebird's [Promise.promisify()](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification).

What's the most quick & simple way to promisify these sorts of library methods?

The following works, but is there an easier way?

```
function geocoderAsync(string) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    return geocoder.geocode(string, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(data);
      }
    });
```

Comment: For a single function that's pretty good - for more you can create a custom promisifier.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this if that's the only odd function in the library. And I think [`Bluebird.fromCallback`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.fromcallback.html) is the function you're looking for.

```
var Promise  = require('bluebird'),
    geocoder = Promise.promisifyAll(require('geocoder')); 

// If that is the only function with the odd callback order
// you could simply re-overwrite the `geocode` function.

geocoder.geocodeAsync = function (string, options) {
    return Promise.fromCallback(function (callback) {
        geocoder.geocode(string, callback, options);
    });
};
```